# Capture size with ansible_facts

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-facts

I would like to scroll through the output of this ansible_facts variable until I find the disk size value C: \ using ansible attribute selection, someone can help me?

It seems that something in the string is escaping and generating an error in the search

**Exit ansible_fact:**

```
ok: [192.168.56.103] => {
    "ansible_facts.disks": [
        {
            "bootable": true,
            "bus_type": "SATA",
            "clustered": false,
            "firmware_version": "1.0",
            "friendly_name": "VBOX HARDDISK",
            "guid": null,
            "location": "Integrated : Adapter 0 : Port 0",
            "manufacturer": null,
            "model": "VBOX HARDDISK",
            "number": 0,
            "operational_status": "Online",
            "partition_count": 2,
            "partition_style": "MBR",
            "partitions": [
                {
                    "access_paths": [
                        "C:\\",
                        "\\\\?\\Volume{e98535da-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}\\"
                    ],
                    "active": false,
                    "drive_letter": "C",
                    "guid": null,
                    "hidden": false,
                    "mbr_type": 7,
                    "number": 2,
                    "offset": 525336576,
                    "shadow_copy": false,
                    "size": 53160706048,
                    "transition_state": 1,
                    "type": "IFS"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My attempt**

```
test : '{{ ansible_facts.disks | selectattr("partitions.drive_letter", "search", "^C$")| map(attribute="size") | list }}'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

[Examples](https://oznetnerd.com/2017/04/18/jinja2-selectattr-filter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the `selectattr` filter, but I managed it with a `json_query`:

```
  - set_fact:
      c_size: "{{ ansible_facts.disks | json_query( partition_query ) }}"
    vars:
      partition_query: "[*].partitions[?drive_letter=='C'].size"

  - debug:
      var: c_size

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ c_size }}"
```

Gives this output:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [192.168.124.8] => 
  c_size:
  - - 53160706048

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [192.168.124.8] => 
  msg: ':[[53160706048]]:'
```

Looks like it's still a couple levels embedded in the originial lists, but it's there.  You can get rid of that by using `c_size[0][0]` or `c_size.0.0`.  Of course, you can use another `set_fact` to assign `c_size.0.0` to another variable.

Comment: I just discovered you can back out of the lists like this: `c_size: "{{ ansible_facts.disks | json_query( partition_query ) | first | first }}"`, instead of `c_size.0.0`.